# Time Series: How can I adjust pd.date_range(freq='B') with the Saturday included. (Python)

Tags: python, time, timestamp, time-series

This is my example code:

```
q=pd.date_range('05/13/2019',periods=100, freq='B')
```

Obviously, it would list out 100 the working days from 05/13/2019 with no Saturday and Sunday. However, in some Asia nations, they are, indeed, working on Saturday. 
How can I fix this ? so that the result should be 100 days from 05/13/2019 with only no Sunday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing two `date_range`s and remove the Sundays from the first one:

```
>>> q = pd.date_range('05/13/2019', periods=100, freq='D')
>>> q2 = pd.date_range('05/13/2019',periods=100, freq='W')
>>> q[~q.isin(q2)]
DatetimeIndex(['2019-05-13', '2019-05-14', '2019-05-15', '2019-05-16',
               '2019-05-17', '2019-05-18', '2019-05-20', '2019-05-21',
               '2019-05-22', '2019-05-23', '2019-05-24', '2019-05-25',
               '2019-05-27', '2019-05-28', '2019-05-29', '2019-05-30',
               '2019-05-31', '2019-06-01', '2019-06-03', '2019-06-04',
               '2019-06-05', '2019-06-06', '2019-06-07', '2019-06-08',
               '2019-06-10', '2019-06-11', '2019-06-12', '2019-06-13',
               '2019-06-14', '2019-06-15', '2019-06-17', '2019-06-18',
               '2019-06-19', '2019-06-20', '2019-06-21', '2019-06-22',
               '2019-06-24', '2019-06-25', '2019-06-26', '2019-06-27',
               '2019-06-28', '2019-06-29', '2019-07-01', '2019-07-02',
               '2019-07-03', '2019-07-04', '2019-07-05', '2019-07-06',
               '2019-07-08', '2019-07-09', '2019-07-10', '2019-07-11',
               '2019-07-12', '2019-07-13', '2019-07-15', '2019-07-16',
               '2019-07-17', '2019-07-18', '2019-07-19', '2019-07-20',
               '2019-07-22', '2019-07-23', '2019-07-24', '2019-07-25',
               '2019-07-26', '2019-07-27', '2019-07-29', '2019-07-30',
               '2019-07-31', '2019-08-01', '2019-08-02', '2019-08-03',
               '2019-08-05', '2019-08-06', '2019-08-07', '2019-08-08',
               '2019-08-09', '2019-08-10', '2019-08-12', '2019-08-13',
               '2019-08-14', '2019-08-15', '2019-08-16', '2019-08-17',
               '2019-08-19', '2019-08-20'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the `.bdate_range` method and the `'C'` (Custom) frequency. Then we pass what we want in weekmask

```
import pandas as pd
weekmask = 'Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat'
pd.bdate_range(start="11-May-2019", periods=10, freq='C', weekmask=weekmask)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-05-11', '2019-05-13', '2019-05-14', '2019-05-15',
               '2019-05-16', '2019-05-17', '2019-05-18', '2019-05-20',
               '2019-05-21', '2019-05-22'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='C')
```

As you see it did not include 12 and 19 May that were Sundays! :)